# How to fix HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output

Tags: httprequest, http, httpresponse

This would be a duplicate, but I really need a good solution. I have tried to research but failed to find anything.
Not to complicate, I know it is easy if I just used a `GET` method, but I needed to use `DELETE` method. Using `DELETE` would be easy for the api that I'm sending the request to directly call its `Delete` method.

I know I should not set the `Body` but, how I'am able to send the `id` to the api?

**Code Snippet:**

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse(); 
Http http = new Http(); 

req.setEndpoint('testsite.com/api/User'); 
req.setMethod('DELETE'); 
req.setBody('29'); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 

try { 
  res = http.send(req); 
} 
catch(System.CalloutException e) { 
  System.debug('Callout error:' + e); 
} 

System.debug(res.getBody());
```

Comment: Why would you want to hardcode a record Id?

Comment: it's being hardcoded because it's just an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the id for the record to be deleted in the request url by appending the id in the end:

```
?accountId=00128000001v6vV
```

and retrive in apex webservice delete method as:

```
RestContext.request.params.get('accountId')
```

Something similar should be available for the other API as well.

Comment: Could also set the endpoint to testsite.com/api/User/29 ? More standard in  REST  APIs to do it this way.

Comment: would it more vulnerable when it comes in security, setting it to the endpoint?

Comment: As far as security is concerned, both POST and DELETE are almost same. If data is transferred over secure HTTP the chances of data breach are minimal. Few things that can effect in either case are:

POST - size could affect, as the data packets are big
DELETE - as id is passed through URL, it could be logged in client browser as cache etc.